# Get ingredients list in a Component from a JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I'm working with React, I have this array on a JSON file

```
[
  {
    "name": "Leia Burger",
    "ingredients": ["cheese", "meat"],
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Luke Burger",
    "ingredients": ["tomato", "meat", "lettuce"],
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Ham Solo Burger",
    "ingredients": ["bacon", "cheese", "meat"],
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Double Ham Solo",
    "ingredients": ["bacon", "cheese", "meat", "cheese", "meat"],
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "All-green Yoda Burger",
    "ingredients": ["cheese", "tomato", "cucumber", "lettuce"],
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "The Chewbacca",
    "ingredients": ["tomato", "cucumber", "cheese", "meat", "meat", "meat"],
    "id": 6
  },
  {
    "name": "Darth Vader Burger",
    "ingredients": ["tomato", "cucumber", "bacon", "cheese", "meat", "lettuce"],
    "id": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "The Emperor",
    "ingredients": [
      "bacon",
      "cheese",
      "meat",
      "bacon",
      "cheese",
      "meat",
      "bacon",
      "cheese",
      "meat"
    ],
    "id": 8
  }
]
```

I have to show the ingredients in a separate component **RecipeIngredients** (right now it's hardcoded)

```
export const RecipeIngredients = () => (
    <div className="ingredients">
        <div>Tomato</div>
        <div>Lettuce</div>
        <div>Meat</div>
        <div>Cucumber</div>
        <div>Cheese</div>
    </div>
)
```

And use that component in another component **RecipeCard**

```
export const RecipeCard = () => (
    <div className="recipe-card">
        <Burger />
        <div className="right-pane">
            <h1>Double Cheese Burger</h1>
            <h2>Ingredients:</h2>
            <RecipeIngredients />
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

I've managed to place the names on the cards (on **App.js**) with the map method

```
function createCard(recipe) {
  return <RecipeCard name={recipe.name} key={recipe.id} />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>React Burgers</header>
      <main>{recipes.map(createCard)}</main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but I'm not being able to show the ingredients, because I'm confused about how it's structured in the JSON. Any help is welcome.

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-loop-through-arrays-in-react-3eaa8a14445

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign your array to a variable, then pass the name of the recipe as props to RecipeIngredients, then from that props, you're gonna find the required object and finally map its ingredients.

So your component will look something like this:

```
export const RecipeIngredients = (props) => {
   const recipe = recipesArray.find((elt)=>elt.name===props.recipeName); 
   return(<div className="ingredients">
           {recipe.ingredients.map((ing)=><div>{ing}</div>)}
         </div>) 
}
```

then you call it like this:

```
   <RecipeIngredients recipeName={"Leia Burger"}/>
```

I hope that's what you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you! That solved it, I passed {props.name} on recipeName and it's working perfectly, now I'm gonna find out how it's this really working.

Comment: happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

First we need to get all `ingredients` :

```
let ingredients = [];

// loop through all recipes and get all the ingredients in `ingredients` array
allRecipes.forEach(recp => ingredients = [ ...ingredients , ...recp.ingredients])

// then new Set(ingredients) will return unique list of ingredients
// [... new Set()] , via this we'll convert the set back to array
console.log([... new Set(ingredients)]);
```

Then we can pass those in props as :

```
// passing as props
<RecipeIngredients ingredients={ingredients}/>

// using from props
export const RecipeIngredients = ({ingredients}) => (
    <div className="ingredients">
        { ingredients.map(ingredient => <div>{ingredient}</div>)}
    </div>
)
```

---

Please do run below snippet, Hope this will clear your doubts

```js
const allRecipes = [
  {
    "name": "Leia Burger",
    "ingredients": ["cheese", "meat"],
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Luke Burger",
    "ingredients": ["tomato", "meat", "lettuce"],
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Ham Solo Burger",
    "ingredients": ["bacon", "cheese", "meat"],
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Double Ham Solo",
    "ingredients": ["bacon", "cheese", "meat", "cheese", "meat"],
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "All-green Yoda Burger",
    "ingredients": ["cheese", "tomato", "cucumber", "lettuce"],
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "The Chewbacca",
    "ingredients": ["tomato", "cucumber", "cheese", "meat", "meat", "meat"],
    "id": 6
  },
  {
    "name": "Darth Vader Burger",
    "ingredients": ["tomato", "cucumber", "bacon", "cheese", "meat", "lettuce"],
    "id": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "The Emperor",
    "ingredients": [
      "bacon",
      "cheese",
      "meat",
      "bacon",
      "cheese",
      "meat",
      "bacon",
      "cheese",
      "meat"
    ],
    "id": 8
  }
]

let ingredients = [];
allRecipes.forEach(recp => ingredients = [ ...ingredients , ...recp.ingredients])
console.log([... new Set(ingredients)]);
```